# Why is my code executing random function inside twice?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've some code written which is to basically build a Simon game. JS and HTML code flow goes like on fresh start the random number generates a number and accordingly the color gets selected but when I open it in browser the random function is executed twice and hence the color blinks twice. Any help is appreciated

## JS Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var gamePattern = [];
  var userClickedPattern = [];
  var buttonColors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
  var level = 0;



  function playSound(key) {
    var audio = new Audio("sounds/" + key + ".mp3");
    audio.play();
  };

  function animatePress(keyPressed) {
    $("#" + keyPressed).addClass("pressed")
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#" + keyPressed).removeClass("pressed")
    }, 100);

  };

  function nextSequence() {
    $("h1").text("level " + level);
    level++;
    var next = Math.floor(((Math.random() * 4)));
    var nextColor = buttonColors[next];
    return nextColor
  };

  function randomColorChooser() {
    var nextColor = nextSequence();
    gamePattern.push(nextColor);
    $('#' + nextColor).fadeIn().fadeOut().fadeIn();
    playSound(nextColor);
    $(".btn").on("click", function() {
      var userChosenColour = $(this).attr("id");
      userClickedPattern.push(userChosenColour);
      playSound(userChosenColour);
      animatePress(userChosenColour);
      checkAnswer(level);
    })
  };

  function checkAnswer(currentLevel) {
    if (gamePattern[currentLevel] === userClickedPattern[currentLevel]) {
      return "success"
    } else {
      return "failed"
    };
  }

  $(document).on("keypress", function() {
    randomColorChooser();
  })
});
```

Comment: dont bind to events in other event handlers.

Comment: @DanielA.White Can you please explain? Newbie here.

Comment: you are calling `.on` in an  event handler for keypress, so everytime keypress fires, it binds to the click event again.

Comment: Every keypress on the document that happens, you are calling the `randomColorChooser()`.  Which apart of its logic is to put a new click event handler on every `.btn` element.  So after the second key press, every time you click a `.btn`, the click logic will happen twice.  After the third keypress, three times, and so on

Comment: @Taplar
@DanielA.White - I separated mt event handlers and my functions so that each event handler calls a different function but still no luck. The random number randomColorChooser is being called twice 
```
function randomColorChooser() {
var nextColor = nextSequence();
gamePattern.push(nextColor);

$(".btn").on("click", function() {
var userChosenColour = $(this).attr("id");
userClickedPattern.push(userChosenColour);
playSound(userChosenColour);
animatePress(userChosenColour);
checkAnswer(level);});

$(document).on("keydown", randomColorChooser);```

Comment: Give then code you've provided - `randomColorChooser` is only called from document.on keypress - if it's being called twice then you're calling `.on("keypress")` twice - so you're possibly including your .js file twice (perhaps an additional time in a bundle?).   Add as the very first line: `alert("myjs")` to see if it's included twice.  If not, you'll need to create an [mcve] here that *demonstrates* the issue.

Comment: @freedomn-m Adding js file twice was the issue. Thanks!